# Create the set of everything in Python

Tags: python, set, intersection

I am looking for a base case for set.intersection

I have an algorithm that takes in a list of sets, the length of the list can be 0, 1, 2, 3, and so on. Given this list, it will return the intersection of all the sets within the list. The returned intersection is then used further down-the-line to be intersected with more things. The code gist and its usage looks something like this:

```
def intersect(list_of_sets):
    return set.intersection(*list_of_sets)

ss1 = intersect(list_of_sets)
# a few moments later . . . 
# . . .
ss2 = set.intersection(some_other_set, ss1)
```

So the issue happen when the list_of_sets is an empty list. This is trouble because it breaks my code. What would be an elegant solution is to re-write the code as follows:

```
def intersect(list_of_sets):
    return set.intersection(*[list_of_sets, set.EVERYTHING])

ss1 = intersect(list_of_sets)
# a few moments later . . . 
# . . .
ss2 = set.intersection(some_other_set, ss1)
```

This way, the returns of intersect under the empty list would be set.EVERYTHING, which correctly intersects with some_other_set to form ss2 as desired.

I know in python floats and ints have maximal values such as INF and such, is there an analogous for sets? The "base case" for addition is "0", the "base case" for set union is the empty set, I need a base case for set intersection, which is the EVERYTHING set. Does it exist?

Comment: A such that A op X = X is known as an *identity*, not a "base case".

Comment: Mathematical set theory has the concept of the "Universe", the set of everything. I don't think programming languages with "set` datatypes have anything analogous.

Comment: So you want a way to intersect rather than subtracting when an empty list is found?

Comment: @ScottHunter arnt you a handful